# Type safe deserialization in TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript, serialization, deserialization

I have this sample TypeScript code that is supposed to deserialize a simple JSON into an instance of class `Person` and then call `foo` method on it, but it doesn't work:

```js
class Person {
    name!: string;
    age!: number;

    foo() {
        console.log("Hey!");
    }
}

fetch("/api/data")
    .then(response => {
        return response.json() as Promise<Person>;
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        data.foo();
    });
```

The output of console show that object is in a proper shape, but it is not *recognized* as `Person`:

```
Object { name: "Peter", age: 44 }
​
age: 44
​name: "Peter"
​
```

Thus when it tries to call `foo` method it fails:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.foo is not a function
>
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/app.js:14
> promise callback* http://127.0.0.1:8000/app.js:12

How can I fix it? Should I use `Object.assign` or there is another better/*native* solution?

```js
let x = (<any>Object).assign(Object.create(Person.prototype), data);
x.foo();
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember, TypeScript is just a way of annotating JavaScript code with type guards. It doesn't do anything extra. For example, saying that the object returned by `response.json()` should be treated as a `Promise<Person>` does not mean it will invoke the constructor of your `Person` class. Rather, you'll just be left with a plain old JavaScript object that has a name and an age.

It looks to me like you'll need to create a constructor for your `Person` class which can create a new instance of a Person based on an object that matches its interface. Something like this, perhaps?

```
interface PersonLike {
    name: string;
    age: string;
}

class Person implements PersonLike {
    constructor(data: PersonLike) {
        this.name = data.name;
        this.age = data.age;
    }

    name: string;
    age: string;

    foo() {
        console.log("Hey!");
    }
}

fetch("/api/data")
    .then(response => {
        return response.json() as Promise<PersonLike>;
    }).then((data) => {
        const person = new Person(data);

        person.foo();
    });
```

I'd also recommend using a type guard instead of the `as` keyword, in case the API you're fetching data from changes. Something like this, perhaps:

```
function isPersonLike(data: any): data is PersonLike {
    return typeof data?.name === 'string' && data?.age === 'string';
}

fetch("/api/data")
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).then((data: unknown) => {
        if (isPersonLike(data)) {
            const person = new Person(data);

            person.foo();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I was thinking that in someway TypeScript _compiler_ was doing something like that under the hood since I am specifying the generic type to be applied.
BTW, what if a class field has a custom type, so it is an instance of another class? I guess that I have to _cascade_ the above approach.

Comment: Do you mean if the type of a property of your class is a second class? In that case yes, you would have to create a new instance of that second class using `new ClassB` in the constructor of your first class.

Comment: Is there a way to generate the type guard (`isPersonLike`) from the interface?

Comment: @FrederickNord I don't know of any tools to do that, but it's possible some might exist. Of course, they'd need a way to know about any other types that are used within your type as well. Generally I do find that writing typeguards is quite a programmatic process

Comment: There is https://github.com/rhys-vdw/ts-auto-guard to generate guard functions from interfaces. I think it could improve by offering a "parse" function to return either an error or the actual type. But it's a start.

Comment: It looks like the current implementation of that `ts-auto-guard` package has a bug that would cause it to throw an error if a typeguard is run on `null`. That's because `typeof null` resolves to `object` but if you attempt to access a property on `null` JS will throw a `TypeError`. The generated typeguards seem to start with a `typeof X === 'object'` check but don't also check that it's not `null` before attempting to access its properties.

Answer (score 1):

> ... is supposed to deserialize a simple JSON into an instance of class Person and then ...

Unfortunately, generic type in TypeScript only works as some kind of model design assistant. It will never be compiled into JavaScript file. Take your "fetch" code for example:

```
fetch("/api/data")
    .then(response => {
        return response.json() as Promise<Person>;
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        data.foo();
    });
```

After compile the above TypeScript file into JavaScript, we can find the code `as Promise<Person>` is completely removed:

```
fetch("/api/data")
    .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    data.foo();
});
```

To implement "type safe deserialization", you need to save class/prototype information during serialization. Otherwise, these class/prototype information will be lost.

> ... or there is another better/native solution? ... BTW, what if a class field has a custom type, so it is an instance of another class?

No, there is no native solution, but you can implement "type safe" serialization/deserialization with some libraries.

I've made an npm module named [esserializer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esserializer) to solve this problem automatically: save JavaScript class instance values during serialization, in plain JSON format, together with its class name information. Later on, during the deserialization stage (possibly in another process or on another machine), esserializer can recursively deserialize object instance, with all Class/Property/Method information retained, using the same class definition. For your "fetch" code case, it would look like:

```
// Node.js server side, serialization happens here.
const ESSerializer = require('esserializer');
router.get('/api/data', (req, res) => {
  // ...
  res.json(ESSerializer.serialize(anInstanceOfPerson));
});

// Client side, deserialization happens here.
const ESSerializer = require('esserializer');
fetch("/api/data")
    .then(response => {
        return response.text() as Promise<string>;
    }).then((data) => {
        const person = ESSerializer.deserialize(data, [Person, CustomType1, CustomType2]);
        console.log(person);

        person.foo();
    });
```